# Swift Bind error on iPad but not on the simulator

Tags: swift, udpclient

I'm getting an error when running my code on iPad but not on the simulator. 
This error is generated on the status from the Bind socket. But, using this on the iPad simulator, this works. But, once executed on my iPad, I'm getting an error. This error is linked to the status as, the status is -1 instead of 0. 
May I ask you to give me a hand on this ?

```
    struct sockaddr_in sockaddr;
    memset(&sockaddr, 0, sizeof(sockaddr));

    sockaddr.sin_len = sizeof(sockaddr);
    sockaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    sockaddr.sin_port = htons(3629);
    sockaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);

    int status = bind(listeningSocket, (struct sockaddr *)&sockaddr, sizeof(sockaddr));
    if (status == -1)
    {
        close(listeningSocket);
        printf("Error: listenForPackets - bind() failed.");
        return -1;
    }
```

Comment: From `man bind`: "the global integer variable errno is set to indicate the error".  Maybe try printing `errno`?

Comment: I do not think that the problem in this but do not want to change the byte order (`htonl`) for `INADDR_ANY`, it consists of zeros

Comment: May I ask why this is tagged [swift]? It looks like plain C code.

Comment: Hmmmmm, because .... just forgot to close an Client/Server App test with the port 3629 on my iPad !!??? Sorry guys ...